# Multiple selection in angular tree

Tags: angular, angular-tree-component

I am trying to override shift+click to select the multiple nodes in the tree. I do the same way as in the tutorial

```
import { ITreeOptions, TreeNode,TREE_ACTIONS,KEYS,IActionMapping} from 'angular-tree-component';
actionMapping: IActionMapping = {
    mouse: {
      click: (tree, node, $event) => {
        $event.shiftKey
          ? TREE_ACTIONS.TOGGLE_SELECTED_MULTI(tree, node, $event)
          : TREE_ACTIONS.TOGGLE_SELECTED(tree, node, $event)
      }
    }
  };
@ViewChild('tree') tree: any;
 treeOptions: ITreeOptions = {
    actionMapping:this.actionMapping,
    getChildren: this.getChildren.bind(this),
    useVirtualScroll: true,
    nodeHeight: 22
 };
<tree-root #tree [nodes]="nodes" [focused]="true" [options]="treeOptions" (updateData)="treeUpdate()" (moveNode)="onMoveNode($event)">
...
</tree-root>
```

but it does not work, property 'TOGGLE_SELECTED_MULTI' does not exist on TREE_ACTIONS.

Answer (score 0):

```
const actionMapping:IActionMapping = {
  mouse: {
    click: TREE_ACTIONS.TOGGLE_ACTIVE_MULTI
  }
};

public options = { 
    actionMapping
  };
```

And HTML Like

```
<tree-root [nodes]="nodes" [options]="options"></tree-root>
```